# Nginx upstream doesn't work with docker deploy stack

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm trying to deploy a stack with docker.

Here is how my stack works:

- nginx-proxy (redirect user requests to the good container)
- website (simple nginx serving a website)
- api (django application, launch with gunicorn)
- nginx-api (serving static files and uploaded files and redirect to the API container if it is an endpoint)

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
    website:
        container_name: nyl2pronos-website
        image: nyl2pronos-website
        restart: always
        build:
          context: nyl2pronos_webapp
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./logs/nginx-website:/var/log/nginx
        expose:
            - "80"
        deploy:
            replicas: 10
            update_config:
                parallelism: 5
                delay: 10s

    api:
        container_name: nyl2pronos-api
        build:
            context: nyl2pronos_api
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: nyl2pronos-api
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8001:80
        expose:
            - "80"      
        depends_on:
            - db
            - memcached
        environment:
            - DJANGO_PRODUCTION=1
        volumes:
            - ./data/api/uploads:/code/uploads
            - ./data/api/static:/code/static

    nginx-api:
        image: nginx:latest
        container_name: nyl2pronos-nginx-api
        restart: always
        expose:
            - "80"
        volumes:          
            - ./data/api/uploads:/uploads
            - ./data/api/static:/static
            - ./nyl2pronos_api/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./logs/nginx-api:/var/log/nginx
        depends_on:
            - api

    nginx-proxy:
        image: nginx:latest
        container_name: nyl2pronos-proxy
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        volumes: 
            - ./proxy:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
            - ./logs/nginx-proxy:/var/log/nginx
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints: [node.role == manager]
        depends_on:
            - nginx-api
            - website
```

When I use **docker-compose up** everything works fine.
But when I try to deploy with **docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose.yml prod**. My nginx config files can't find the different **upstreams**.

This is the error provided by my service **nginx-api**:

```
2019/03/23 17:32:41 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "api" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:2
```

See below my **nginx.conf**:

```
upstream docker-api {
    server api;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxxxxxxxxxxxxx;

    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /static/;
    }

    location /uploads {
        autoindex on;
        alias /uploads/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://docker-api;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

If you see something wrong in my configuration or something I can do better, let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is happening because `nginx-api` service is up before the `api` service.

**but i added the `depends_on` option?**

you are right, and this option should work for a `docker-compose up` case.
but unfortunately not on `docker stack deploy`, or, as the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) put it:

> The depends_on option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode
>   with a version 3 Compose file.

**ok, so what can i do now?**

nothing. its actually not a bug-

docker swarm nodes (your stack services) are supposed to recover automatically on error. (thats why you define the `restart: always` option). so it should work for you anyway.

if you are using the compose file only for deploying the stack and not on a `docker-compose up` - you may remove the `depends_on` option completely, it means nothing to docker stack.